# Include a file after plugin loaded?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin and I want to include some file only when it satisfied some conditions or user choose to include them. But after I include, its functions (in those file include later) do not run ?

```
if ( isset( $registered[$add_on] ) && ! isset( $enabled_add_ons[$add_on] ) ) {        
        include( $registered[$add_on]['file'] );
}
```

These in those file :

```
function add_on( $meta_boxes ) {
    $feature_meta_box= array(
        ...
    );

    array_unshift( $meta_boxes[1]['fields'], $feature_meta_box);

    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter('add_metabox', 'add_on');
```

Can anybody tell me how can I load this file ?

Comment: could it be the variable `$feature_metabox` that below is called `$feature_meta_box`?

Comment: I fix it out and it still does not work :(